# How to avoid hardware damage with dd

Tags: dd, hardware, pv

I wanted to create an encrypted USB-stick. In the tutorial I used it said something like 'to avoid pattern based attacks dump random input to the drive'. So I did by dding /dev/urandom to the drive. It took some time, the stick got really hot, but I tought whatever. I had to do that a bunch of times, becuase things did not work and now the stick does not answer any more. Does not show up on lsblk, does not show up on lsusb, does not light up when plugged in.

Of course this can be a coincidence, but I would like to avoid that. So how can I?

I have seen people pipe the dd input into pv, sth like this:

```bsh
dd if=./sth.iso | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb
```

This is neat to see a progress bar. But I know you can use pv to slow down throughput through a pipe.

```bsh
echo unix stackexchange|pv -qL 10
```

Now what is a safe amount of throughput? Are there other ways to avoid damage? Am I mistaken to think that I broke the drive with dd?

Comment: Strange, cause urandom is slow and what you did was just writng to the device, rather slowly so it shouldn't happen. I had a stick that was in metal casing but it was getting hot during work. Sure enough it stopped working after some time. I would call it a design fault.

Comment: Generally there's no need to use `dd`. You could have just `cat /dev/random >/dev/sdb`. Or `pv /dev/random >/dev/sdb`. But neither these nor your original should have fried the stick

Comment: You did not mention if you tried the drive on another system. Sometimes I have issues that  get solved by using different ports or across reboots with thumb drives. Even the LEDs may not light up, like yours. Doesn't hurt to test.

Comment: I can try that. But I do think it was because of the heat and the missing input throttling.

Answer (score 1):

Heat is the Enemy of Plastics/Electronics/Cables : Plastics can easily melt or even burn ; CPUs and MotherBoards become hot and hence require cooling through fans ; Cables can disconnect the Internal Wiring.

There are many known instances of Heat Damage of USB Drives, Eg :
https://www.lfs.net/forum/thread/15558-Ahhhh!-Pen-Drive-has-MELTED!!!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Duu1OkJ9ue0
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/usb-cable-melted-after-plugging-into-pc-front-io.3706385/

In your case, either (1A) the USB Drive was of low quality or (2A) the writes were too much too fast, which made the heat rise too quickly and gave no chance to cool and hence the BreakDown, either of the MotherBoard or the Connections (the Internal Wiring) or the Storage Elements.

To avoid this, (1B) you should go for better quality USB Drives and (2B) install tools like `hddtemp` & `smartctl` and monitor the temperature and Proactively Disconnect when heating up. With `hddtemp` or `smartctl`, you can also check whether the accessing or the writing makes it too hot and what at rate. You can then throttle accordingly.